# Android Firebase - Writing Data to Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is a very simple question and I looked at a lot of tutorials but I am not getting how to write data from android studio to firebase, mainly creating sub-categories and hash map, etc.

I am trying to make this happen in firebase from scratch. Please help

Database structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your custom object:

```
public class Position {
    public String Lat;
    public String Long;
    public Position (String Lat, String Long) {
        this.Lat = Lat;
        this.Long = Long;
    }
}
```

Code to save data, you can place it anywhere:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().push()
    .child("Position").setValue(new Position("Something", "Something"));
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That helps! Thanks.